# How to make insertOrUpdate a compiled query in Slick?

Tags: slick

I've been using [Slick's `insertOrUpdate` since its release in 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18985147/4525394) version without any issue.

Right now I'm trying to improve my code performance and insertOrUpdate is the bottleneck (according to jProfiler). I thought I could improve this by using 
a compiled query but as far as I can see, invoking `insertOrUpdate` I have a `SingleInsertOrUpdateResult` and not a `Query` object.

Is there a way to get a compiled query for `insertOrUpdate`? Or is there another way to improve it's performance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as for the the other insert operations like `+=`: You have to compile the `Query` and then call `insertOrUpdate` on the resulting `CompiledQuery`.

Comment: But in my case I don't have any intermediate query, all I do is calling `insertOrUpdate` on my `TableQuery`.