# insertOrUpdate with Slick 3

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

Where in the Slick 3 [documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/) is it documented on how to do an `insertOrUpdate`-like operation?

Comment: You mean something like [this code](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/3.0.0/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/InsertTest.scala#L131)? (From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18985147).) BTW: asking for external resources is off-topic on SO.

Comment: @GáborBakos It'd be nice to have that documented in http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/. Surprised there appears to be nothing about insertOrUpdate. Thanks for the BTW. :) If you don't mind, where can I read about this rule? I'd like to become a better SO citizen. :)

Comment: I think you can submit an issue to their tracker, probably referencing [issue 6](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/6) to fix the missing documentation problem (unless you find an issue with that topic). The off-site resource thing is on http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, point 4.

Comment: Question is valid, just reformulate it as "how to do insertOrUpdate in Slick 3?"

Answer (score 3):

The insertOrUpdate method that comes with slick 3.x is [limited to MySQL Only](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.1/supported-databases.html).  You won't get any warnings/code documentation, it will just throw Integrity exceptions.

In order to upsert with Slick if using Postgres, you can use [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg).

Answer (score 2):

This support is there in Slick . Look at this merge : [Pull Request Merged Here](https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/782) The support was added in Slick 2.1 .
These are also called `upsert` statements.

However i would think you would want to use plain SQL(for the native DB you are using) for this kind of requirement.
Look [here](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1.0/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/InsertTest.scala#L130) for examples of how to use Slick to do this.

Basically code that looks like the following ,

```
val reviews = TableQuery[<Class extending Table>]
val upsert: DBIO[Int] = reviews.insertOrUpdate(<value to be inserted>)
```

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleInsertActionComposer` contains method required: [doc link](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/api/#slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleInsertActionComposer)